# How to use spark toLocalIterator to write a single file in local file system from cluster

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark job which writes my resultant dataframe in local filesystem. Currently it is running in `local` mode and so I am doing `coalesce(1)` to get a single file as below

```
file_format = 'avro'      # will be dynamic and so it will be like avro, json, csv, etc
df.coalesce.write.format(file_format).save('file:///pyspark_data/output')
```

But I see a lot of memory issues (OOM) and takes longer time as well. So I want to run this job with master as `yarn` and mode as `client`. And so to write the result `df` into a single file in localsystem, I need to use `toLocalIterator` which yields `Row`s. How can I stream these `Row`s into a file of required format (json/avro/csv/parquet and so on)?

```
file_format = 'avro'
for row in df.toLocalIterator():
    # write the data into a single file
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You get OOM error because you try to retrieve all the data into a single partition with: `coalesce(1)`

I dont recommend to use `toLocalIterator` because you will re-rewrite a custom writer for every format and you wont have parallele writing.

You first solution is a good one :

```
df.write.format(file_format).save('file:///pyspark_data/output')
```

if you use hadoop you can retrieve all the data into one on filesysteme this way : (it work for csv, you can try for other) :

```
hadoop fs -getmerge <HDFS src> <FS destination>
```

Comment: But writing to a file will be inside a spark job. I cannot use `hadoop` binary inside my python script

Comment: you can do it at the end of your job ? you will use sh for spark-submit any way ?

Comment: It is an ETL pipeline code and some dataframes are written to hdfs and some into local. So I would prefer to do it programmatic way